# I want to return the status of the batch file from one batch file to the other batch file ..if it gets executed it should return success else failure

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is the first batch file:

```
@echo off
echo chaitu HI FROM ONE
```

This is the second batch file:

```
@echo off
echo from harsha
call chaitu.bat
ECHO.%ERRORLEVEL%
ECHO AFTER VALUE

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :failure
else
GOTO SUCCESS


:success
echo success 
GOTO END

:failure
echo failure
GOTO END

:END
ECHO THIS IS THE END
```

My problem here is if I give the correct batch file name then it should return success and should show  success or if I give the incorrect batch file it should return failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what should be checked:

- successful call of other batch file, or
- result of the commands in the other batch file.

I give examples for both.

**Checking the call of the other batch file**

Main batch file contains:

```
@echo off
call OtherBatchFile.bat 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto Failure
echo Other batch file was called successfully.
goto :EOF

:Failure
echo Other batch file could not be called.
```

And the other batch file contains:

```
echo Other batch file running ...
rem Do something ...
exit /B 0
```

**Checking the result of the commands in the other batch file**

Main batch file contains:

```
@echo off
set "Result=none"
call OtherBatchFile.bat
if "%Result%"=="none" goto CallFailed
if "%Result%"=="fail" goto Failure
echo Other batch file executed the commands successfully.
goto :EOF

:Failure
echo Other batch file reported a failure on execution.
goto :EOF

:CallFailed
echo Other batch file could not be called.
goto :EOF
```

And the other batch file contains:

```
echo Other batch file running ...
if exist "%windir%\notepad.exe" ( set "Result=success" ) else ( set "Result=fail" )
```

As you can see, this solution checks also successful call of the other batch file as the other batch file is designed to modify value of environment variable *Result* in any case.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 2000 and later use this as finishing sentence

```
exit /B [exitCode]
```

Put on [exitCode] the desired errorlevel to pass on.
[check here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) where there is a full explanation.

`%ERRORLEVEL%` (as shown in your code) is just an enviroment variable (observe % chars) which may be or may not be set with the correct exitCode depending on what OS you use.  But to any windows OS, this works:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 255 GOTO Label255
IF ERRORLEVEL 254 GOTO Label254
   .
   .
   .
IF ERRORLEVEL   2 GOTO Label2
IF ERRORLEVEL   1 GOTO Label1
```

Please be sure to check in descending order.  This is because `greater than` condition is tacit on IF ERRORLEVEL (and the only one that this syntax allow)

On the other hand, you can communicate whatever between batchs seting and reading enviroment vars.  In that case you must be careful because that is a shared space, so two executing batchs may conflict, or you can have an inconsistent state after an incomplete batch execution. So on the called batch can set any variable as `SET myvar=myvalue`.  Please do not use SET errorlevel=  to avoid confusion and problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've fully understood what you want, but you should try adding the following to the end of the first batch file:

```
cmd /c exit 0
```

This will cause it to set ERRORLEVEL to 0 if it successfully executes.

Also the else statement in your second batch file is not valid syntax - just remove it.